# PDO Exception Error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi I am getting PDO Exception, am i doing something wrong ? I tried to use the same query to insert data in PhpMyAdmin and it works though.

Error :Type: PDOException
Code: 42000

> Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at
>   line 1 File: X:\SproutTech\Fashion-Blog\cms\app\Models\Post.php Line:
>   36

```
try {

    $statement = $this->connection->prepare("INSERT INTO posts(title,content,image_path,tags,author,status,cat_id) VALUES(:title,:content,:image_path,:tags,:author,:status,:cat_id");

        $statement->execute(array(  ":title"=>$array['title'],
                                    ":author"=>$array['author'],
                                    ":content"=> $array['content'],
                                    ":image_path"=>$array['image_path'],
                                    ":tags"=>$array['tags'],
                                    ":status"=>$array['status'],    
                                    ":cat_id"=>$array['cat_id'], ));

} catch (PDOException $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();

}
```

Comment: one extra `,` after `":cat_id"=>$array['cat_id']` . remove it, rest looks fine to me. Also try once `$statement->execute(array(":title"=>$array['title'],":content"=> $array['content'], ":image_path"=>$array['image_path'],":author"=>$array['author'],":status"=>$array['status'],":tags"=>$array['tags'],":cat_id"=>$array['cat_id']));
` (I don't think sequence change is the issue here,but it's a proper way to put things in exact sequence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One `)` is missed and `"` is misplaced in your first code line, so change it like below:-

```
$statement = $this->connection->prepare("INSERT INTO posts(title,content,image_path,tags,author,status,cat_id) VALUES(:title,:content,:image_path,:tags,:author,:status,:cat_id)");
```

check ) and quote in last